# Restore missing rows from pg_dump backup

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a database where some records were accidentally deleted from one of the tables. There is a recent plaintext dump available that was created using pg_dump. The table has a uuid column. Is there a way to restore the missing rows into the original table from the dump?

The table schema has been altered since the dump was created, but none of the changes should prevent old records from being imported as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to restore the dump into a different database and extract the interesting rows from there. Then you can restore them into the original table.